# Show attribute of foreign key in add_form in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, field

Is it possible show an attribute of foreign key in add_form django?

For example:

```
#models.py
class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, db_column='Name')  # Field name made lowercase.
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='Id', primary_key=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=60, db_column='Description')  

#admin.py
class TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['name','product','get_description']
    readonly_fields = ['get_description']

    def get_description(self):
        return self.product.description
```

Naturally this code raise exception the ErrorFields in 'get_description'.

But, does exist a way to show the 'get_description' when I insert an entry of model Test?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can override the [`ModelAdmin.get_form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form) and alter the form that it uses, to add a field of your choosing, filled with whatever you like. For example:

```
#admin.py
class TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['name','product']

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if obj.product:
            # self.form.base_fields is an OrderedDict(field_name=form.Field, ...)
            self.form.base_fields['product_description'] = forms.CharField(required=False, initial=obj.product.description)
            self.form.base_fields['product_description'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
        return super(TestAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

That will add a readonly text input field as the last field in your "add" form. If you wanted it placed in a different spot witin the form, you'd have to work out some logic to rebuild `self.form.base_fields` as a new `OrderedDict` in exactly the order you'd like.